# AWK - use column value from input to create new columns on output

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a file like this:

```
       Date     Time   Level Gridsize    Miss      Temp    Parameter ID
 1988-05-16 12:00:00      -3        1       0     27.060    -1            
 1988-05-16 12:00:00      -3        1       0     9.0300    -2            
 1988-05-16 12:00:00      -3        1       0     1.2000    -3            
 1988-05-17 12:00:00      -3        1       0     27.100    -1            
 1988-05-17 12:00:00      -3        1       0     9.0200    -2            
 1988-05-17 12:00:00      -3        1       0     1.2300    -3            
 1988-05-18 12:00:00      -3        1       0     27.190    -1            
 1988-05-18 12:00:00      -3        1       0     9.0400    -2            
 1988-05-18 12:00:00      -3        1       0     1.2200    -3
```

These are temperature data from sensors in different locations. The field `Parameter ID` determines if the data was taken from sensor -1, -2 or -3. I'm exporting this data to a CSV file to analyze it. The desired format is:

```
   Date     Time           -1       -2        -3    
1988-05-16 12:00:00      27.060    9.0300    1.2000                     
1988-05-17 12:00:00      27.100    9.0200    1.2300
1988-05-18 12:00:00      27.190    9.0400    1.2200
```

It groups data by date **and** time, and separates in columns regarding the value of `Parameter ID`.

I'm not sure about how doable this is with AWK, but I'm once I mostly use SSH to prepare this data, a solution with AWK is very interesting for me. Also, if there are other tools to achieve this on bash, I'm interested :) (sed, whatever, but got to use native linux commands because I'm not allowed to install anything on the server)

---

**What I'm doing nowadays**

Nowadays I run a code for each sensor

```
$ awk '$NF == "-1" {print $1";"$2";"$6}' > netcdf_extract_1.csv
$ awk '$NF == "-2" {print $1";"$2";"$6}' > netcdf_extract_2.csv
$ awk '$NF == "-3" {print $1";"$2";"$6}' > netcdf_extract_3.csv
```

And import them on python. Then I group them by date and time and got my table.

Comment: Did you try anything at all?

Comment: Well, nowadays I'm getting 3 files, one for each sensor and joining them on python. Also, I tried something. I'll post the codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU **`awk`** solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"; }
     NR > 1{ a[$1"\t"$2][$7]=$6 }
     END{ 
         printf "Date\tTime\t-1\t-2\t-3\n"; 
         for (i in a) print i,a[i][-1],a[i][-2],a[i][-3] 
     }' file | column -t
```

- `a[$1"\t"$2][$7]=$6` :

  - `a` - multidimensional array
  - `$1"\t"$2` - array key/index constructed by concatenation of *Date/Time* fields
  - `[$7]` - inner array indexed with *Parameter ID* field value
  - `$6` - crucial value from *Temp* field

---

The output:

```
Date        Time      -1      -2      -3
1988-05-16  12:00:00  27.060  9.0300  1.2000
1988-05-17  12:00:00  27.100  9.0200  1.2300
1988-05-18  12:00:00  27.190  9.0400  1.2200
```

Comment: I got an error when I run this on ubuntu 17.04: awk: `line 2: syntax error at or near [
awk: line 5: syntax error at or near [` Any clue?

Comment: @rvbarreto, check if you copy/pasted properly. It works fine, see the screenshot https://ibb.co/jKqVLw

Comment: I may be letting something behind. Just did the same and got the error, [https://ibb.co/cuNS0w](https://ibb.co/cuNS0w)

Comment: @rvbarreto, My first sentence clearly says **GNU** awk. That's the main condition.

Comment: Ok, I found the problem. For people using awk or gawk before v4, true multiarrays are not supported. In this case, you have to use associative arrays: `awk 'BEGIN { PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"; } NR > 1 {a[$1"\t"$2,$7]=$6; if($NF==-1){b[$1"\t"$2]=$6}} END{printf "Date\tTime\t-1\t-2\t-3\n"; for (i in b){print i, a[i,-1],a[i,-2],a[i,-3]}}'`

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "Date\t","Time\t", "-1\t", "-2\t", "-3\t";
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc" }
    NR > 1{ a[$1] = a[$1]" " $6 ; b[$1] = $2;next }
    END{ for ( i in a ) print i, b[i], a[i] }' file1 | column -t
```

Output:

```
Date        Time      -1      -2      -3
1988-05-16  12:00:00  27.060  9.0300  1.2000
1988-05-17  12:00:00  27.100  9.0200  1.2300
1988-05-18  12:00:00  27.190  9.0400  1.2200
```

As Roman has everything in one array I splittet the task up to two arrays.

Comment: Nice! It's similar to the code I posted on Roman's solution, but much more elegant! Thanks!